# Codeigniter remove index.php in linux server

Tags: php, codeigniter

When i paste the `.htaccess` file code on my local machine it works fine like my url's are fine without `index.php` but when i upload the same code to linux server then the url again needs `index.php` can somebody guide me how to remove the `index.php` on a linux server...

this is my .htacces code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

this is my .htaccess code and as of i explained this work fine on my local windows machine but when i upload the same code to linux server then my rounting engine does't works

Comment: Check mod_rewrite enable on your server

Comment: neither do we have your .htaccess file nor your index.php file, neither do we have an error message, how could we possibly know what went wrong?

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: this is my .htaccess code and as of i explained this work fine on my local windows machine but when i upload the same code to linux server then my rounting engine does't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure mod rewrite is turned-on in your server.
2. Also make sure that .htaccess file is in the same folder where your index.php resides.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on your htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Hope this code helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend setting a .htaccess at the same level as the applications folder, and put the following code in it.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```